# Adding TypeScript to existing create-react-app app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having difficulties adding TypeScript to an **already existing** create-react-app application. Previously I've always added it before starting the project, simply by `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`, but that doesn't work now.

The only "solution" I found [here](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/108) is:

1. Create a temporary project with `react-scripts-ts`
2. Copy `tsconfig.json`, `tsconfig.test.json` 
   , `tslint.json` from the temporary project src folder to your project's `src` folder.
3. In `package.json`, change all the references to `react-scripts` to `react-scripts-ts` in the scripts section.

This just seems like a weird workaround, and not very efficient. Does anyone know if it's possible to add it in a better way than this?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As of react-scripts 2.10 you can add **TypeScript** to an existing project or when creating a new project.

**existing project**

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest --dev
```

...then rename your `.js` files to `.tsx`

**new project**

```
yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript
```

You can read more [in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript).

If you are having trouble, the following from the troubleshooting section of the docs might help:

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> If your project is not created with TypeScript enabled, npx may be
> using a cached version of create-react-app. Remove previously
> installed versions with npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn
> global remove create-react-app (see #6119).

Comment: This works pretty smooth. One thing I experienced when moving from a pre-existing ES-CRA to TS-CRA is having to change ESLINT settings: https://www.robertcooper.me/using-eslint-and-prettier-in-a-typescript-project

Comment: What about tsconfig file? Don't we need to add that?

Comment: @iRohitBhatia the documentation says "You are not required to make a tsconfig.json file, one will be made for you", but this is only true for new projects as the file is not created for existing projects. what should we do for existing projects... just create one?

Comment: digging a litter deeper, "CRA automatically creates an tsconfig.json file for you when it notices a .ts file in your source folder", it will automatically create that file for you.

Comment: it doesn't work, `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ` show up

Comment: @UMR yes it isn't work

Comment: @UMR See Neisam's answer. I had the same issue. CRA doesn't seem to consistently create a tsconfig.json file, so you might just have to manually add it.

Answer (score 46):

If you want to add TypeScript to the existing react app use below command

```
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

Rename at least one file from `js/jsx` to `.ts/tsx`. For example, rename `index.js` to `index.ts` or `index.tsx` and then start the server. This will generate the `tsconfig.json` file automatically and you are ready to write React in TypeScript.

Comment: if I rename `index.js`, no error happened, but if I do it to other files, this error show up `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ...`. Also there is no`tsconfig.json` file generated

Comment: @UMR you need to manually initialize typescript `npx tsc --init` and set `"jsx": "react"` in tsconfig.json

Comment: I still have to add the TypeScript dependencies to the package.json:  "@types/jest": "^27.5.2", "@types/node": "^16.18.13", "@types/react": "^18.0.28", "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",

Answer (score 25):

You can add typescript to an existing project using one of the following commands:

To add TypeScript to an existing Create React App project, first install it:

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

or

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

You can read more [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/)

But the problem is when you are changing a file except index.js like `App.js` to `App.tsx`  it gives you an error that module not found error can't resolve './App' . The source of this issue is lacking a tsconfig.json file. So by creating one the error would be removed. I recommend using the below tsconfig:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you dont use --save. but --save-dev

Answer (score 2):

This answer would have been the best alternative at the time of writing, but now CRA has built-in TS support. [See the top answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54600139/1332403) I'll keep this for historical purposes.

---

You can use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to add typescript to your project's webpack config, which is a better alternative to ejecting.

If you're not specifically sure how to add typescript from there, [here's a guide on how to do that.](https://medium.com/@justin.pathrose/configure-react-project-using-typescript-and-webpack-f69faee3e915)

Comment: It seems ejecting is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There is [a recent pull request adding Typescript](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/2815). It's not merged yet.

Also, the next major version of CRA will upgrade to Babel 7, which supports Typescript.

So I'd suggest you to wait a few weeks. It should be really easy then to add TS to any CRA project.

Comment: CRA 2 has been released, but it seems that support for Typescript has been postponed: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18118349

Answer (score 2):

Nothing works if decided to add typescript in an existing create-react-app project. Finally, I created a brand new throw-away application using a typescript template and took the following tsconfig.json, and pasted it into my existing project. all good now but it is a weird solution.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is not generating tsconfig.json for me either.

Comment: I had to do this too.  Before, it would only work if I *only* changed `src/index.js` to `src/index.tsx`.  If I changed anything else, it would break.  Needed to add a tsconfig file myself.

Answer (score 2):

### Add TypeScript to an existing React 18 project [using official guide](https://react.dev/learn/typescript#adding-typescript-to-an-existing-react-project)

- Add type definitions

  ```bash
  npm install @types/react @types/react-dom --save-dev
  ```
- Add `tsconfig.json`. For example, take a look at [the sample app](https://github.com/akhanalcs/reactjs/tree/main/hooks-examples).

  ```json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2022",
      "module": "ES2022",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "strict": true,     // This makes noImplicitAny as true
      "lib": [
        "ES2022",
        "dom"             // This is important
      ],
      "jsx": "preserve"   // This is important
    }
  }
  ```
- Change filename extensions. If you have JSX in your file, change its extension to `.tsx`, otherwise change it to `.ts`.

  For example:

  - Change `App.js` to `App.tsx`
  - Change `index.js` to `index.tsx`
- Start the app

  ```bash
  npm start
  ```
- Fix type errors

  For example: This error in `index.tsx`

  [image]

  For eg: use non-null assertion operator

  ```
  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
  ```

Your app should work just fine at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

then Create a tsconfig.json file in root folder

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After checking your issue I created a template using React, Typescript, Tailwind and Storybook

https://github.com/dsilva2401/react-typecript-tailwind-storybook

Comment: Your answer should inform the asker how to solve a problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33528938)

Answer (score -7):

To start a new Create React App project with TypeScript, you can run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Comment: The question literally states that he has an existing project that he'd like to convert.

Comment: haji enjoori rotbe nemigiri.