# What is the best way to use sx prop in MUI v5?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, material-ui, jsx, jss

I have started using MUI v5 with makeStyles in my previous project. After deploying, I faced a huge delay in loading page's CSS. So I started searching that found out *`makeStyles` is deprecated in MUI v5*.

MUI suggests to use `sx` prop instead. That's fine. But the problem here is I don't want to write my JSX and CSS/JSS code together. For example:

This is what MUI says:

```
// App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <Grid sx={{ bgcolor: 'yellow', mx: 5, pt: 2, border: 1 }}>
      This is a test!
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is somehow what I expect:

```
// style.js
export default {
  myGrid: {
    bgcolor: 'yellow',
    mx: 5,
    pt: 2,
    border: 1,
  },
};
```

```
// App.js
import style from "./style";

function App() {
  return <Grid sx={style.myGrid}>This is a test!</Grid>;
}

export default App;
```

I wanna know what is the best pattern to use JSS and JSX files independently with `sx`? Is it possible to get VSCode suggestions while typing `sx` props in another file?

Comment: The way you're using the style.js file makes me think you should look into Theming (i.e. applying a global style to your entire app). If you want to re-use the styled Grid component then you should look into styled components. The sx prop should generally only be used for minor tweaks.

Answer (score 6):

Check this out :) We can store styles in a single object.

Use `Record<Keys, Type>` to define parent object type.

After that you'll get suggestions when you typing keywords. etc: `backgroundColor`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

```
//styles.ts
import { SxProps, Theme } from "@mui/material";

export const navBarStyles: Record<string, SxProps<Theme> | undefined> = {
    notification: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        "&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible": { backgroundColor: "white" }
    },
    test: {
        color: 'green'
    }
}
```

Then import navBarStyles

```
//navbar.tsx
import { navBarStyles } from '../styles/mui/navbar';
```

Apply Styles

```
//navbar.tsx
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
          <IconButton sx={navBarStyles.notification}>
            <KeyboardArrowDownRoundedIcon htmlColor='#ffffff' />
          </IconButton>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm using this strategy as well. But is there a standard way to also reference your local theme properties with this strategy? So that we can reuse the theme values?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with TypeScript. If TypeScript is not already configured in your project, you would have to add it (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54600139/2241714) for help with that).

Then you can make a styles.ts file with all of your component styles by using the `SxProps` type.

```js
// Styles.ts
import { SxProps } from '@mui/material'

const myGrid: SxProps = {
  bgColor: 'yellow',
  mx: 5,
  pt: 2,
  border: 1
}

export default { myGrid }
```

By using the SxProps type on your stlye object, you'll get code completion with all of the MUI sx props.