# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on app using reactJS, while using map function finding this error on console **TypeError: data.map is not a function** but the API data calling was successful found in console.log but to display data on window error is popping again here's my code and also attaching console output image.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Products = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    getProduct();
  },[]);

  async function getProduct() {
    var res = await axios.get("http://localhost:9900/products");
    console.log(res.data);
    setData(res.data);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
      {data.length > 0 && (
        data.map((product) => {
          return (
              <>
                  <div className="col-md-3 mb-4">
                      <div className="card h-100 text-center p-4 border-0 " key={product.productId} >
                          <NavLink to={`/products/${product.productId}`}><img src={product.productImage} className="card-img-top" alt={product.productTitle} height='250px' /></NavLink>
                          <div className="card-body">
                              <h5 className="card-title mb-0">{product.productTitle.substring(0, 12)}...</h5>
                              <h6 className="card-text text-center">Rating {product.productRating}</h6>
                              <p className="card-text lead fw-bold">${product.productPrice}</p>
                              <NavLink to={`/products/${product.productId}`} className="btn btn-outline-dark">Buy Now</NavLink>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </>
          )
      })
      )}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Products
```

[image: console image as output]

Comment: Did you mean to `setData(res.data.content)`? `res.data` appears to be an object.

Comment: [Add TypeScript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967495/adding-typescript-to-existing-create-react-app-app)) to catch such errors already in the IDE. You'd have to [generate TypeScript definitions](https://blog.theodo.com/2022/08/typescript-interfaces-from-java/) for your back-end models. New contenders are [TypeSpec](https://microsoft.github.io/typespec/) from Microsoft and [Taxi](https://docs.taxilang.org/) from [Orbital](https://orbitalhq.com/docs).

Comment: I would check the data type of res.data when it is returned. It's possible you need to unwrap or deconstruct the response. Saying it won't map is a clear indicator that your data state is changing from an array object.

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshot I can see that the `axios.get()` response object `res.data` contains the array in the `content` property. So either replace

- `data.map` by `data.content.map` in the JSX or
- `setData(res.data)` by `setData(res.data.content)` in getProduct()

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving an Object from your API call, so use `res.data.content.map()` or only save the `content` key, which holds the array you're looking for:

```
async function getProduct() {
    var res = await axios.get("http://localhost:9900/products");
    if (res?.data?.content) {
        setData(res.data.content);
    }
}
```